# Google sheet autosorting

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like some help solving the error in the following google script code.
Error given is "Missing ; before statement. (line 1, file "Code")"

```
 Function onEdit(event) {
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 13;
  var tableRange = "A4:R100";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you made a typo here. The "f" in "Function" should in lowercase.

Comment: Thanks, have it sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getColumn() == 2){   
    var range = e.range.getSheet().getRange("A1:B10");
    range.sort({column:2});
  }
}
```